# jQuery - Trigger click on another link inside div when another is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been going round in circles trying to get this to work and I am sure it is something very simple!

I have a page with divs that include a number of links and I want to bind a click on one of the links in the div to fire a click on another link.

An example of the structure:

```
<div>
<a>A link that is to be binded to another</a>
<a>Link that needs to be fired</a>
</div>
<div>
<a>A link that is to be binded to another</a>
<a>Link that needs to be fired</a>
</div>
<div>
<a>A link that is to be binded to another</a>
<a>Link that needs to be fired</a>
</div> <!-- This repeats upto around 20 times on a page -->
```

So if someone clicks the first link inside the div, it triggers a click on the 2nd one!

Hopefully that makes some sense. My brain has been looking at this for too long that I fear I wont solve this quickly on my own.

Cheers

Comment: And where is your jQuery code? What have you tried so far? And if both links are visible what is the point of clicking one to activate another?

Comment: Just first Link onClick to trigger onClick on 2nd?

Comment: @JensonMJohn - Yeah, but how can I make that happen by looping through all the divs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("div > a").first().on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next("a").trigger("click");
});
```

Something like this?

Comment: This may be a silly question, is there a way to tweak this to fire the 2nd next link?

Comment: `$(this).nextAll("a").slice(0,1);` try this